# Get the heights as a value into another column

Tags: python, python-3.x

this must be a simple question, because i cant seem to find the answer.
I have a table of contour data in GIS - one column called NAME have the contour heigh with an added text " m" (example "450 m", "5 m", etc.). 
I want to copy the heighr numbers without the " m" string.
Any advise?

In excel the following formula would work:
 " = Value(Left(NAME,Len(NAME)-2))"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to write a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly so that we can best help you.

Answer (score 0):

slicing the last two characters of a string in python:

```
print("500 m"[:-2])
```

would output

```
500
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with python strings, you can use the "replace" function:

`"450 m".replace(" m", "")`

that will give you an output of "450"

The pattern is:

variable.replace("string you want to replace", "replacement")

```
m_string = "450 m"
no_more_m = m_string.replace(" m", "")
```

The value of no_more_m will be "450"

Answer (score 0):

This way is also efficient to remove 'm'

```
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip('m'))
```